# Why does the pop method in my code for stacks does not execute?

Tags: java, stack, queue

I am trying to make a simple code for Stacks using two Queues. I understand the concept, and I have tried the following code to implement this.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class StackWithQueues {

Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
int size;

public StackWithQueues() {

    this.size = 0;

}

public void push(int ele) {

    q1.add(ele);
    size++;

    System.out.println("Pushed "+ele);
}

public void pop() {

    while(!q1.isEmpty()) {

        q2.add(q1.peek());
        q2.poll(); 

    }

    int popped = q2.peek();

    size--;
    q1 = q2;

    System.out.println("Popped "+popped);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StackWithQueues s = new StackWithQueues();

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        s.push(i+1);

    s.pop();
    s.pop();
    s.pop();


}

}
```

I can't understand why the `pop()` method is not doing anything. The console shows the following output on execution.

> Pushed 1
>   Pushed 2
>   Pushed 3
>   Pushed 4
>   Pushed 5

I would appreciate if someone can explain what is going wrong with the `pop` method here.

Comment: You have to ask one question at a time. Doesn't edit your question into another it invalidates answers. If you have different question ask it separately.

Comment: @talex I understand that, but the question is very closely related to the previous issue and question, hence posting a new question would be like posting a duplicate.

Comment: Nop. Now it is completely different question. And you set up people who tried to help you. If anyone read this question now he will downwote existing answers because they do not answer the question.

Comment: @talex, if you say so, I shall ask a new question and revert this to the original post I had. Thank you.

Comment: You welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pop` method has an infinite loop. It keeps adding elements to `q2` without removing anything from `q1` (since `q1.peek()` doesn't remove the head of the queue), so `q1` will never become empty.

Something like this seems to work:

```
public void pop() {
    int popped = 0;
    while(!q1.isEmpty()) {

      popped = q1.poll ();
      if (!q1.isEmpty ()) {
        q2.add (popped);
      }
    }

    size--;
    Queue<Integer> temp = q1;
    q1 = q2;
    q2 = temp;

    System.out.println("Popped "+popped);
}
```

Note that it still lacks a test for empty stack.

You had several issues:

1. This is a stack, so pop should return the last element pushed, not the first.
2. In the first pop you set `q1 = q2`, and from this point on you only have 1 queue. You should create a new empty queue for q2 (or assign to it the original q1).

Comment: Yes, I see that now, but can you check the update of my question